# Dimensional shift with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Here's my problem at the moment. I have a sequence of 4 80 x 80 images, that is an (80,80,4) numpy array. I want to update this array by shifting the first three images to the left and inserting the new image at the end. That is if my original array is (x,y,z,w) where x,y,z,w are 80x80 images, I want to update this array to become (y,z,w, NEWIMAGE) where the new image is 80x80. The updated array should also have an (80,80,4) dimension. What's the most efficient way to do this? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Probably need some additional explanations here, as a simple list containing the images is a quick and easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.roll`, and then reassign?

```
arr = np.roll(arr, -1, axis=0)
arr[-1, :, :] = newarray
```